# How do I get this code working which is intended to change the text of a button upon clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the text and color of a button when the user clicks it.
I am trying to change the text from "Search" to "Close".
I have attempted to code it, and have posted what I tried in jsfiddle.

now another problem is I can't figure out why jsfiddle isn't running the code, haha, but maybe someone can figure it out regardless of the jsfiddle glitches.

Without further ado, my code...

HTML:

```
<form>
  <p>

      <button class="btn submit" type="submit" onClick="changeHeight();">Search</button>


      <button class="btn cancel" onClick="changeHeight2();">Reset</button>  

      <div id="SearchDiv">Here I am</div>

    </p>
</form>
```

CSS

```
p{
  text-align:center;
  background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
}
.btn{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color:rgb(255,255,255);
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:0;
}
.submit{
 background-color: rgb(44,228,191);
}
.submit:hover{
  background-color:  rgb(24, 188, 156)!important;
}
.submit:active{
   background-color: rgb(15,121,100)!important;
}
.cancel{
    background-color: rgb(244,123,130);
}
.cancel:hover{
    background-color: rgb(237,28,36)!important;
}
.cancel:active{
    background-color: rgb(154,12,19)!important;
}





#SearchDiv {
  background-color:purple;
  height:50px;
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
function changeHeight() {
    $('#SearchDiv').fadeIn(500);

}

function changeHeight2() {
    $('#SearchDiv').fadeOut(200);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fdkzp9dm/8/

Comment: In the left top Frameworks and extensions section change `onload` to `No wrap in <body>`. As you have inline func calls.

Comment: Also you are using button use `innerText` http://jsfiddle.net/fdkzp9dm/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of things you need to change:

1. You need to change the fiddle from `onload` to `No wrap in <body>` as @Shaunak correctly commented.
2. You need to pass the element if you're not selecting it in the function. So you either do `onClick="changeHeight($(this))"` or inside the JS function you do `$(el)`.
3. You need to check for `el.text() == "Search"` and to set using `el.text("Close")`, since you're checking the text inside and not a value attribute if you're doing `el.value` (that returns undefined for your example).
4. The last glitch is because the button is of type `submit`, and whenever clicking it the request failed and it overwritten the HTML.

So, basically:

```
function changeHeight(el) {

    $('#SearchDiv').fadeToggle(500);  

    if (el.text()=="Search")  {

        el.text("Close");
    }
    else {

        el.text("Search");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdkzp9dm/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your button like:

```
<button class="btn submit" type="submit" onClick="changeHeight($(this), $('#SearchDiv'));">Search</button>
```

Change your javascript function like so:

```
function changeHeight(btn, div) 
{
    if (div.is(":visible") )
    {
         btn.val("Search").css("color", "#ffffff"); // Color: White

         div.fadeOut(500);
    }
    else
    {
         btn.val("Close").css("color", "#000000"); // Color: Black

         div.fadeIn(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the`css` and the `text` jquery's attributes will do the work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_id').click(function(){
        $(this).text('another text')
        $(this).css('height', '100px')
    })
})
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arochajuan2/ehoqoe0f/)